# android project not appear in file>new

Tags: java, android

my O.S is windows 7 32 bit i installed java jdk 6 ,downloaded eclipse and install android SDK ,the problem is android project does not appear in file>new only appear android application project i tried a lot of versions but not worked , I need to know how can i start with application like in android project not what exist in android application project I try to Run it but this error appear 
[2012-11-17 02:54:42 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2012-11-17 02:54:42 - Emulator] 
[2012-11-17 02:54:42 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2012-11-17 02:54:42 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
please help me how to appear android project like before, or how to work with that android application project, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to start an android project **without** having the premade "Hello world" application?
I recommand downloading the new bundle that you can find on [Android developement](http://www.developer.android.com/)
All you need to do is run the Eclipse application file and everything should be set up allready.
I think it doesent really matter anyways, you will still have the basic project there, but you can just delete the elements from the code. Hope I understod your question correctly.